# Ceiling Light with no switch to turn off

Tags: electrical

We bought an older home there was an old ceiling fan in the kitchen with a pull string.So we changed it and put a new light fixture in .It works fine except we can't turn it off.The switch in the kitchen turns on onother ceiling light in the kitchen.but not the new one. It is the only switch in the kitchen we tried the one in the hall to no luck.Hopefully someone knows whats wrong

Answer (score 6):

You removed the switch for your light fixture when you removed the pull chain. If you want a switch, you'll need to run a line from the fixture to a location on the wall where you can install a junction box and switch. This may require opening up your walls and/or ceiling depending on the access you have.

Comment: +1 It sounds like the OP has little familiarity with electricity and would do well to call in a pro.

Answer (score 6):

There is no switch on the wall. It's annoying that anyone would run a light like that, but there you go. You may find they did that by taking a spur off of an upstairs socket circuit. There are 3 options to deal with it:

- Dig into your walls and run a wall switch. This is a lot of mess, time, and cost
- Install another pull-chain fixture
- Install a radio controlled on/off switch and put the control on a wall bracket where you'd want the switch to be

If it was me I'd do the last option. Radio controls have come down in price to where they are very affordable. They are also pretty reliable and easy to install. Far easier and cheaper than ripping into your walls, and much more elegant than a pull-chain.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed one more option. If the chandelier is always on, I would recommend doing the following:

1. Get a smart device such as a google home or amazon alexa echo device
2. Buy smart bulbs and plug them into the chandelier

This way you save money and time, and it's also pretty cool!